# PHP incremental file names

Tags: php, filenames

I have this function that checks for a filename. If it exists, it increments it by one following this patter:

```
image.jpg
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

The problem comes on the 4th image, it comes back with `0.jpg`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
...
$filetarget = $this->make_image_filename($directory, $new_filename, $extension);

if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filetarget)){
    $error[$index] = 'copy';
}
...

private function make_image_filename($directory, $name = '', $extension){
    if(empty($name)) $name = 'NULL';
    $filetarget = $directory.$name.$extension;

    if(file_exists($filetarget)){
        $name = $this->increment_filename($name);

        return $this->make_image_filename($directory, $name, $extension);
    } else {
        return $filetarget;
    }
}


private function increment_filename($name){

    $index = $this->get_filename_index($name);

    if(is_numeric($index)){
        $pos = strpos($name, $index);
        $name = substr($name, 0, $pos);
    }

    if(is_null($index)){
        $index = 0;
    }

    ++$index;

    return $name.$index;
}

private function get_filename_index($name){
    // CHECK FOR INDEX
    $i = 1;
    $index = substr($name, -$i);
    $last_chars = substr($name, -$i);

    while(is_numeric($last_chars)){
        ++$i;
        $last_chars = substr($name, -$i);
        if(is_numeric($last_chars)){
            $index = $last_chars;
        }
    }

    if(is_numeric($index)){
        return $index;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I am in the process now of isolating this code on my local server to run some tests. Can you see anything inherently flawed in this process?

Comment: can you show code where you call `make_image_filename()` I don't see any problem, and trying your functions I don't have any problem with incrementing. So maybe problem is with parameters send to `make_image_filename()` for the 4 time.

Comment: Looks ok to me too, would be useful to see where `make_image_filename()` is called. However, it looks like `increment_filename()` could be responsible for returning `0` if `$name` is an empty string (''.0 == '0').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function I use to do the same thing:

```
function make_unique($full_path) {
    $file_name = basename($full_path);
    $directory = dirname($full_path).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $i = 2;
    while (file_exists($directory.$file_name)) {
        $parts = explode('.', $file_name);
        // Remove any numbers in brackets in the file name
        $parts[0] = preg_replace('/\(([0-9]*)\)$/', '', $parts[0]);
        $parts[0] .= '('.$i.')';

        $new_file_name = implode('.', $parts);
        if (!file_exists($new_file_name)) {
            $file_name = $new_file_name;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $directory.$file_name;
}
```

(except it make file names like `image(1).jpg` `image(2).jpg`)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function get_next_file_name($file) {
    if (!preg_match('/^(\D+)(\d*)(\.\S+)$/', $file, $match)) {
        throw new Exception('bad file name format');
    }
    return $match[1] . (empty($match[2]) ? 1 : ($match[2] + 1)) . $match[3];
}
echo get_next_file_name('image.jpg'), "\n";      // prints image1.jpg
echo get_next_file_name('image1.jpg'), "\n";     // prints image2.jpg
echo get_next_file_name('image999.jpg'), "\n";   // prints image1000.jpg
```